# Why does my funnel look like that?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking, goals

I've set up a goal with a funnel on Google Universal Analytics. The funnel starts at one domain and the second step is in another domain. I'm using linker to pass the client id to the new domain.

The weird thing is that it looks in the report like there are many entrances directly to the second step, which doesn't make sense. The only way to get to that step is to click a link in the first step. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

What happens is that users who are not logged in yet get redirected to the sign in page and the GA code doesn't get executed until after they are redirected back after they login. So the login page gets a new client id.

The solution I came up with was to tweak with the redirection logic (devise) and to pass the _ga parameter to the login screen.